# xtermjs doesn't display correctly and shows crooked text

Tags: javascript, layout, xtermjs

I'm saving data from a tmux session with capture-pane into a file.txt and I get for instance this result:

```
PC1:/path$ cd /usr
PC1:/usr$ ll
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 May 21  2019 [1;34m.[0;39m/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug  1  2019 [1;34m..[0;39m/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Mar 17 15:09 [1;34mbin[0;39m/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Apr 12  2016 [1;34mgames[0;39m/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Feb  8 09:44 [1;34minclude[0;39m/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Feb  8 09:44 [1;34mlib[0;39m/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Nov 26 14:52 [1;34mlocal[0;39m/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 May 21  2019 [1;34msbin[0;39m/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Feb  8 09:44 [1;34mshare[0;39m/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 May 21  2019 [1;34msrc[0;39m/
PC1:/usr$`
```

If I do `cat file.txt` it displays correctly with colors. If I write that some data to xtermjs it shows all crooked:

[image]

I've tried:

- Adjusting the cols, rows on the Terminal options (I get the current columns and rows with `tput cols` and `tput lines` on linux)
- Using "xterm-addon-fit"
- I've tried several ways of loading the file just to see if I'm not losing some information in the copy/pasting
- I tried with the package xterm-for-reacth
- I also tried vanilla js but had the same issues

Nothing worked. At this moment I just want to find a way of getting the text from a tmux session and display it correctly on xtermjs.

You can see the issue in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-flower-zoyow8?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 2):

edit:

xtermjs only accepts CRLF (aka \r\n) so if the \r is converted to \r\n will make it work.

---

I had several wrong assumptions:

- That xtermjs `write` would process line endings (as it processes everything else)
- There were tabs on my text

I only found out the issue when I rendered the line endings and noticed there were no tabs at the start.

The weirdness in the image above is just the word wrap. xterm works focused on adding lines and not loading full screens.

The example below works albeit only for testing purposes.

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Terminal } from "xterm";
import "./styles.css";
import "xterm/css/xterm.css";

const txt = `
PC1:/path$ cd /usr
PC1:/usr$ ll
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 May 21  2019 [1;34m.[0;39m/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug  1  2019 [1;34m..[0;39m/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Mar 17 15:09 [1;34mbin[0;39m/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Apr 12  2016 [1;34mgames[0;39m/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Feb  8 09:44 [1;34minclude[0;39m/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Feb  8 09:44 [1;34mlib[0;39m/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Nov 26 14:52 [1;34mlocal[0;39m/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 May 21  2019 [1;34msbin[0;39m/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Feb  8 09:44 [1;34mshare[0;39m/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 May 21  2019 [1;34msrc[0;39m/
PC1:/usr$`;

let terminal;
export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    terminal = new Terminal();
    terminal.open(document.getElementById("terminal"));
    const lines = txt.split(/\n/);

    lines.forEach((l) => terminal.write(l + "\r\n"));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <div id="terminal" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Seems the file conversion stripped the CR ('\r'), prolly because of saving it as a file replacing CRLF with NL (which is just '\n' in unix-likes). As a VT100 clone xtermjs needs proper CRLF to do the full "move cursor to the left and one line down" thingy.

Comment: @jerch, yes you are right. Although I don't think anything was stripped and it was just the way the backend sends it. It didn't help that the backend was sending \r and a linux file I was testing with was using \n. So none worked. There's also the convertEol option but I didn't try it. https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/blob/4.14.1/typings/xterm.d.ts#L613

Comment: Ah ok - well then it prolly got directly saved from the app's data stream without passing it through a PTY. Normally the PTY would do the NL to CRLF replacements, means cat'ting the file's content in a proper terminal session in xtermjs should work again. With bypassing the PTY layer you basically have to do the replacements yourself. `convertEol` should work for your specific case, but is not further advertised, because it creates frictions for ppl that in fact use a PTY.

Comment: What do you mean the `convertEol` is not advertised? My main strategy to understand it was to was checking the d.ts file.

Comment: Yes it is listed there, as it is part of the official API, but has created several issue reports in the past, where ppl had it set to true, while using a PTY. Using xtermjs with a PTY is the expected to work default setup, thus I typically dont recommend to play with `convertEol`. If you know the technical details/implications (like never mix it with PTY data), it is fine to use as well.

Comment: Just noticed you are part of the contributors, thanks so much for the library! It's incredible! 

Hope I'm not intruding but maybe you could help me with this: How do I make the height dynamic? 
I can change the rows but it's always fixed. I'm using the fit-addon, I thought the addon was for that. 

I googled it but can't find an answer. If you prefer, I can create a specific question for this.

And thanks again!

Comment: I think thats better for a new question than deep within comments of an unrelated topic.

Comment: Indeed I had a lot to say... I created a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71706920/xtermjs-dynamic-height-not-updating-correctly.