# xtermjs dynamic height not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, css, layout, xtermjs

I'm trying to make the height of xtermjs dynamic. I've looked around but the solutions don't seem to solve my issue. I played with CSS but the problem doesn't seem to be there. I'm also using the xterm-addon-fit.

As an example I created this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-xtermjs-dynamic-height-mvs714) to show the issue. I've added a dragging pane that has a somewhat hard to see black bar in the bottom. When I drag it, the xtermjs component doesn't resize.

In the image below, the black box with numbers (xterm) should be inside the orange box after we resize the orange box.
[image: codesandbox screenshot]

I've used a component to make it easier to test, but it happens if we resize the window in other ways.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to call `fit` on a resize again. The addon has no means to query/observe size changes itself.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @jerk, if we `fit` when the resize happens, it fixes the issue.
This [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-xtermjs-dynamic-height-mvs714) with an extra [hook](https://usehooks.com/useWindowSize/) makes it work. Although now to test it, you have to drag the console pane up and down instead of using the custom component.

```js
  // It resizes xterm when the height changes
  useEffect(() => {
    fitAddon.fit();
  }, [height]);
```

Notice the auto scroll stops. Depending on the scenario, you might want to scroll to the bottom.